# Require fails on a PhantomJs test

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, browserify, mocha-phantomjs

I have a simple library,

```
-- src/lib.js --
function libtest() {
    return 2;
}
```

that I want to test, which I gather will need PhantomJs.  I have a test file:

```
-- test/lib.test.js --
var fs = require('fs');
var assert = require('assert');
describe('Test module', function() {
    var s = fs.readFileSync('../src/lib.js', 'utf8');
    eval(s);
    it('Shows name', function() {
        assert.equal(libtest(), 2);
    });
});
```

which I make ready for the browser:

```
# browserify lib.test.js -o tests.js
```

and then include in my main page:

```
-- test/index.html --
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Mocha Tests</title>
  <link href="../../node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>
  <script src="../../node_modules/mocha//mocha.js"></script>
  <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
  <script src="tests.js"></script>
  <script>
    if (window.mochaPhantomJS) mochaPhantomJS.run();
    else mocha.run();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

however, when I run the tests:

```
# grunt test
```

I get the following error:

> Running "mocha_phantomjs:all" (mocha_phantomjs) task TypeError:
>   'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   'fs.readFileSync('../src/lib.js', 'utf8')')
>
> at file:///Users/ekkis/Development/tst/test/tests.js:5
>   at
>   file:///Users/ekkis/Development/tst/node_modules/mocha//mocha.js:529
>   at file:///Users/ekkis/Development/tst/test/browser/tests.js:10    in
>   s at file:///Users/ekkis/Development/tst/test/browser/tests.js:1    in
>   e at file:///Users/ekkis/Development/tst/test/browser/tests.js:1    at
>   file:///Users/ekkis/Development/tst/test/browser/tests.js:1090 Unsafe
>   JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame
>   with URL
>   file:///Users/ekkis/Development/tst/node_modules/mocha-phantomjs-core/mocha-phantomjs-core.js.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

which seems to be complaining about the `fs` being undefined.  however, if the `require('assert')` worked, I would imagine the `require('fs')` should work.  but I don't quite know the context in which this is run.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. the answer is simply to include the library in the `.html`.  since the tests run within the browser then the library will be available.  like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>
  <script src="../../node_modules/mocha//mocha.js"></script>
  <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
  <script src="../../src/lib.js"></script>
  <script src="tests.js"></script>
```